# Is it possible to make a non boolean method without parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The usual method would be like

```
public datatype name(parameters) {}
```

Is it possible to have an integer method without parameters? if so how?

example:

```
public int WorkPlease(){}
```

Comment: have you tried it

Comment: `public int WorkPlease(){ return 1; }`

Comment: return type of a method does not depends on the parameter you are passing it but the type you are returning from it.

Comment: Here is your documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values

Answer (score 6):

int is return type, hence fuction must return some integer value like below.

```
 public int WorkPlease(){ return 5;}
```

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: sorry, but I can not add comment as per minimum reputation requirement. In place of increasing my reputation, you have decreased it. so Sad.

Comment: It is the correct answer, why should it be a comment? Because the answer is short?

Answer (score 3):

Very much so. On a more general note, a method can take an input and return an output. However, both are optional and independent of one another. So you can have all four combinations:

- Only **input**
- Only **output** (the one you are asking about)
- **Both** input and output
- **Neither** input or output

Output-only methods are quite normal, if you have an object and wish to return some properties from this object (e.g. `GetFirstName()`). There are no constraints on the data type of the output, so it can also include integers.

An example of what you are asking, could be a method which returns the next year, in case you needed that for something:

```
public int GetNextYear()
{
   int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
   return currentYear + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking here, but this example of yours technically has input (the current date and time), it's just not provided by the caller.

Comment: @Alex in that sense, there will always be some sort of "input". In nilsK's example, he has hard-coded the number '5' (so a user input). Another use could be a method which returns a random number. But since this requires a seed, this will also have a pseudo-input. So if the question is, if you can generate an integer out of nothing, then the answer would be no. But I don't think that's what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you simply need to **return** an integer, so you could take some values from the current class' fields as input or return some other value independent of the internal fields and properties.

```cs
class Example {
  int someMember = 42;

  public int WorkPlease() {
    return someMember * 2;
  }// or any other operation

  public int WorkPlease2() {
    return random.Next();
  } // return something independent of the class
}
```